# Probability of event happening at least once with changing probabilities

Tags: probability

Here's an example : the chance of getting a certain item as a drop from a boss in a video-game is 1/50. If you don't get the item, the chance then becomes 1/47 for your next kill. If you still didn't get it, it becomes 1/45, and so on. It keeps getting more and more common, but it's never guaranteed.

How can I calculate the probability of getting the drop from a sequence of say 3 kills, assuming that I know the probability for each of the events?

I know how to calculate it when all the probability doesn't change (ex: how likely you are to get a six at least once by rolling a dice 10 times) but I'm not sure how to approach this when the probability of the event occuring is different for each occurence.

I hope the question is clear enough, I'm just a video-game enthusiast trying to make sense out of this!

Comment: I'm sorry but I never play video games so I don't understand the expression "a drop from a boss".

Comment: You kill an enemy and they "drop" some loot when they die, for example in-game currency, rare items, potions, that sort of thing. It's your reward for defeating them. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Yes it does. Then your probability will probably be (in the case you get what you want only on the third try)= Probability of failing on the first try x Probability of failing on the second try x Probability of winning on the third try. Of course, the probability of failing = 1 - Probability of winning.

Comment: Probability of at least one drop in a sequence of 3 kills is what you want? 

I believe it is just 1 - P(0 drops in a sequence of 3 kills) = 1 - (49/50 * 46/47 * 44/45)

Comment: Alternatively you can proceed using @BernardMassés way 

Probability of exactly 1 drop in the sequence is given by p1 = 1/50*49/50*46/47 + 49/50*1/47*49/50+49/50*46/47*1/45.

Probability of exactly 2 drops in the sequence is given by p2 = 1/50*1/50*49/50+1/50*49/50*1/50+49/50*1/47*1/50.

And probability of exactly 3 drops in the sequence is p3 = 1/50*1/50*1/50.

And your desired probability would be 1-(p1+p2+p3) which agrees with the answer I gave above.